# Dynamically causing a vertical nav bar to become horizontal on screen resize

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to create a dynamic nav bar. By default, I want the nav bar to display vertically in a div which spans the entire height of the page, but when resized, I want the bar to become horizontal. Here's a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have tried to mould my approach based off [W3Schools suggestions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp), by adding `display:block;` to my `ul` but it doesn't change anything. My understanding of media queries isn't the best, but I have also tried to alter the width and height of the left div (dark grey):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    .nav-container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #333;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #333;
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

**Edit**:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: block;
}

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-holder img {
  height: auto;
}

#navigation-div {
  margin-top: -300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-ul li a {
  display: block;
}

.nav-link {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #333;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #333;
  }
  .nav-container nav,
  .nav-container nav ul,
  .nav-container nav ul li,
  .logo-holder {
    display: inline;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
  #navigation-div {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo-holder">
      <img src="#" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-div">
      <nav class="nav left-nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav-ul">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="">
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <li>Blog</li>
          </a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <li>Store</li>
          </a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="">
            <li>Contact</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your approach there is no media query. Just add add the media query from your code + float: none;

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your media query might not be called at all because the max width is pretty small at 200px.

Inside your media query you'll need to set the display property of the navigation elements and the logo to inline, so that they display side-by-side. (You could also consider using flexbox for this) You'll also need to reset some of the properties that are defined higher up, like the line-height of the h3 logo element.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-container{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #333;
      border-bottom: 0.5px solid #333;
   }
  .nav-container nav,
  .nav-container nav ul,
  .nav-container nav ul li,
  .logo-holder,
  .logo-holder h3 {
      display: inline;
  }
  .logo-holder h3 {
      line-height: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrea, thanks for your answer. I've moulded my code based on your approach, but the navigational links don't seem to appear. Can you maybe see my edited question to see where I am implementing your approach incorrectly?

Comment: Hi Freddy, you seem to be using quite a few layout techniques (floats, flexbox, different display values) in your code, it will be easier to keep track of how everything works together if you just go with one.

The reason you can't see the navigation links is that there's a top margin of -300px being applied to #navigation-div, so it's above the top of the screen.

Are you using Chrome devtools or something similar? If not, I highly recommend it! It makes it much easier to figure out what's going on with your elements.

Comment: [Here's](https://jsbin.com/fuherog/edit?html,css,output) a jsbin with some comments on your code, hope it's useful

Comment: Hey Andrea, thank you for your help! The comments were super useful for helping me understand the issues I self inflicted. Just to be clear, my navbar now works thanks to you! :)